# Russian Peasant Multiplication Python using recursive-tail

Tags: python, recursion, multiplication

I tried making this code and run it, but the result showed "None".
I've edited by adding another else in the loop function, then it actually produces a int result of '57' which is not exactly the answer.

```
def double(n):

    return n*2

def halve(n):

    return n//2

def mult(m,n):

    def loop(m,n):

            if n>1:
                if n%2 != 0:
                    return m + loop(double(m),halve(n))
                else:
                    return m #added another else
            else:
                return m

    if n>0:
            return loop(m,n)
    else:
            return 0

print(mult(57,86))
```

Comment: what is it supposed to do?

Comment: `86>1` and `86%2 == 0`, you are lacking one more `else` in the `loop` function.

Comment: It was supposed to print the result of multiplication of 57 * 86 using the Russian peasant multiplication algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by simple recursion

```
def double(n):
    return n * 2

def halve(n):
    return n // 2

def mult(m, n, a = 0):
    if n % 2 != 0:
        a = a + m
        m = double(m)
        n = halve(n)
    if n % 2 == 0:
        m = double(m)
        n = halve(n)
    if n != 0:
        return mult(m, n, a)
    return a

print(mult(57, 86))
```

by nested function

```
def double(n):
    return n * 2

def halve(n):
    return n // 2

def mult(m, n):

    def loop(m, n, a = 0):

        if n % 2 != 0:
            a = a + m
            m = double(m)
            n = halve(n)
        if n % 2 == 0:
            m = double(m)
            n = halve(n)
        if n != 0:
            return loop(m, n, a)
        return a
    return loop(m, n)

print(mult(57, 86))
```

Comment: thanks, but is it possible doing it by recursive of the function itself?

Comment: But how to actually make it in tail-recursive algorithm form?